# Using a php array as argument to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php

I've a function which feeds a chart with fixed data:

```js
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'CPU Temp'],
        ['2004', 340],
        ['2005',  460],
        ['2006', 1120],
        ['2007',  540]
    ]);
}
```

I'd like to replace the fixed data with the one read from a DB table containing two columns: `date` and `temperature`. The read data is stored in the `$json` variable:

```json
[
  {"datain":"2021-04-20 12:00:03","temp":"39.2"},
  {"datain":"2021-04-21 00:00:05","temp":"40.2"},
  {"datain":"2021-04-21 12:00:03","temp":"40.8"},
  {"datain":"2021-08-01 12:00:12","temp":"47.2"}
]
```

Here's my bad code:

```js
let date= "";
let temp = "";
for (let i = 0; i < <?php echo count($json)?>; i++){
    date = <?php echo $json[0] ?>;
    temp = <?php echo $json[1] ?>;
}
  
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'CPU Temp'],
        [date,  temp]
    ]);
}
```

How can I make this work?

EDIT:
Code after being edited with @trincot's suggestions:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Temp'],
    ...<?php echo $json; ?>.map(({
      datain,
      temp
    }) => [new Date(datain), parseFloat(temp)])
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'CPU Temp History',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
} <
/script>
```

Original code is here:[chart code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Comment: What is the structure/content of `$json`? Can you give explicit sample data in PHP or JSON format?

Comment: Sure:(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [datain] => 2021-04-20 12:00:03
            [temp] => 39.2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [datain] => 2021-04-21 00:00:05
            [temp] => 40.2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [datain] => 2021-04-21 12:00:03
            [temp] => 40.8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [datain] => 2021-08-01 12:00:12
            [temp] => 47.2
        )

)

Comment: How do I display that info?

Comment: ok:   [{"datain":"2021-04-20 12:00:03","temp":"39.2"},{"datain":"2021-04-21 00:00:05","temp":"40.2"},{"datain":"2021-04-21 12:00:03","temp":"40.8"},{"datain":"2021-08-01 12:00:12","temp":"47.2"}]

Comment: It is not needed to copy code from an answer back into the question. Stack Overflow works well with question and answer kept separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your `$json` is an array of objects with two properties, you'll need to convert that to an array of arrays (pairs):

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Date', 'CPU Temp'],
       ...<?php echo $json; ?>.map(({datain, temp}) => [new Date(datain), +temp])
    ]);
}
```

So this just injects the whole JSON inside the array literal that is given as argument to `arrayToDataTable`. The `.map` call converts the plain objects to pairs and:

- the date strings are converted to `Date` objects
- the temperature strings are converted to numbers. It is a pity that your PHP code has somehow stored the temperatures as strings. That is odd. It would be better practice to have them there with a number data type, not a string data type.

When you look at the source via your browser, you should see something like this:

```js
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Date', 'CPU Temp'],
       ...[{"datain":"2021-04-20 12:00:03","temp":"39.2"},{"datain":"2021-04-21 00:00:05","temp":"40.2"},{"datain":"2021-04-21 12:00:03","temp":"40.8"},{"datain":"2021-08-01 12:00:12","temp":"47.2"}].map(({datain, temp}) => [new Date(datain), +temp])
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you but I don't get any errors now as I said. The chart just doesn't display. Will update my original code to reflect your suggestions. Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh I thought you referred to the code at the start of your question. Didn't realise you meant my answer's code worked. Looking at the JSON, I see that there are multiple lines with the same date (just different time). You might want to verify the source of your data if you intended to have only one figure per day.

Comment: OMG! Yes! that could be an issue. Will see if I can change the data. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like I'm dealing with strings. Here's the what the browser sees: function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Date', 'Temp'],
          [...[{"datain":"2021-04-20 12:00:03","temp":"39.2"},{"datain":"2021-04-21 00:00:05","temp":"40.2"},{"datain":"2021-08-01 12:00:12","temp":"47.2"}].map(({datain, temp}) => [new Date(datain), temp])]
        ]);

Comment: Yes, that is expected (JSON doesn't know Date objects). The "datain" strings are all converted with `new Date(datain)`: that is all that remains. But I see something strange: there are too many brackets there. There should not be an opening bracket just before the `...`.

Comment: I removed it with no avail :(

Comment: SOLVED!! I converted string to float: [new Date(datain), parseFloat(temp)]

Comment: Right, I just spotted now that your JSON has strings for the temperatures. That is confusing. That means that they are strings in your PHP, and thus in your database. That is something you should look at. These really should be numbers in a good database design. The conversion should really happen at the source. Good that you spotted this. The conversion can also be done with a simple unary `+` (updated in answer).

Comment: Will check my php code. In the DB the temp field is set to float. Thank you again!!